# Using a batchsize greater than 1 when using Tensorflows c++ API

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow model trained in Python and frozen with the `freeze_graph` script. I've succesfully loaded the model in c++ and made inference for a single image. However, it seems freeze_graph sets the batchsize to only a single image at a time, since I am unable to pass the model a tensor with more than one image.

Does anyone know a way of changing this? I haven't been able to locate where in the script it actually happens.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Okay, so I scrapped Keras just to eliminate any black magic that might be doing, and I set a batch size of 16 when defining the network with Tensorflow.

If I print the graph def, the placeholder has a shape:

```
node {
  name: "inputs"
  op: "Placeholder"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "shape"
    value {
      shape {
        dim {
          size: 16
        }
        dim {
          size: 50
        }
        dim {
          size: 50
        }
        dim {
          size: 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I attempt to load and run the model in c++ with a tensor of shape 16 x 50 x 50 x 3, I get this error:

```
tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.cc:433] Check failed: 1 == NumElements() (1 vs. 16)Must have a one element tensor
```

Something must be happening somewhere when I freeze the graph?

Comment: `freeze_graph` doesn't 'set' the batch size of the model. How were you feeding the inputs in your original model?

Comment: I've built the model using Keras, which I believe uses a variable batchsize per default. This made me assume that `freeze_graph` must do something in the case of a placeholder with a dimension of variable size, but I might be wrong. Is there a way I can check what the shape of the placeholder actually is?

Comment: You can try printing out the graph in text form using `graph.as_graph_def()` and see if the placeholder has the shape attribute set.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far -- I've updated my OP, if you have the time to take a look!

Comment: Is the graph that you show before or AFTER running `freeze_graph`? It will be useful to show the one after `freeze_graph`.

Comment: That was actually before running `freeze_graph`, but I've just checked and the inputs placeholder looks the same after running the script. Could I be doing something wrong when loading the graph in c++? I'm simply using the `LoadGraph` function from the Tensorflow `label_image` c++ example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a stupid mistake on my part. When getting the output of the graph, I called `.scalar<float>()` on it. This worked perfectly fine when I only had one input image, and therefore only one output, but obviously I can't cast a vector to a scalar. Changing it to `.flat<float>()` fixed my issue.